# How do I get the data returned using a closure from a method?

Tags: swift

I have this method:

```
internal func getCoordinate( addressString : String,
                             completionHandler: @escaping(CLLocationCoordinate2D, NSError?) -> Void ) {

       let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(addressString) { (placemarks, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {
                    let location = placemark.location!

                completionHandler(location.coordinate, nil)
                return
            }
        }

        completionHandler(kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid, error as NSError?)
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
self.getCoordinate(addressString: "Summerville, SC", completionHandler: <#T##(CLLocationCoordinate2D, NSError?) -> Void#>)
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
let currentLocation = self.getCoordinate(addressString: "Summerville, SC", completionHandler: <#T##(CLLocationCoordinate2D, NSError?) -> Void#>)
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a value from an asynchronous function just like it was a normal synchronous return value.

You have to access the value inside the closure to ensure that the asynchronous method has already finished execution. If you were trying to access that value outside the closure, you couldn't ensure in any way that the value is already set, since asynchronous methods return before they would actually finish execution, but you can use a closure to ensure this.

There are some methods (such as `DispatchQueue`s or the use of a 3rd party framework, like [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit)) other than completion handlers to solve this issue, but you will never be able to use a value from an async method the same way, without any limitations as you would with a value from a synchronous method.

This is how to access the value returned from the completion handler:

```
self.getCoordinate(addressString: "Summerville, SC", completionHandler: { coordinate, error in
    guard error == nil else {return}
    //use the coordinate here
})
```

Just a minor improvement to your current method: instead of returning an invalid coordinate in case the geocoding was unsuccessful, I would return `nil` as the coordinate in this case.